# How to get the current value of a clock in UPPAAL and store it in an integer variable?

Tags: model-checking

Could anyone tell me how to get the current value of the clock variable and store in an integer variable. I've tried k=t(where k is the integer and t is the clock), but it throws an "incompatible type error". I also tried k=(int)t, but it throws an "Unexpected T_INT" syntax error..

Is there any type casting available for clocks in UPPAAL to get the current value of a clock and store it in a variable?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible, because of the way time is treated (symbolically). If you use the UPPAAL simulator, you can see that the clock values are not represented concretely, but rather as clock constraints. Therefore, you cannot really talk about the clock being some value, but rather the current clock valuation satisfying a number of constraints, and therefore the clock is in some interval.

You don't specify what you want to achieve, so a few related pointers:

- You can however compare clocks to integer variables
- If you want to know the maximum value a clock can reach, you can use a "sup: clock" query